# Enforce US Formatted Dates in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, formatting

There are threads about this exact scenario on stackoverflow and I've used all methods I can to try to find a solution, but I'm baffled as to why these date format methods sometimes work, and sometimes don't, when dealing with some resources who reside Mexico.

I have some macros for US documents that provide many different types of information regarding some dates (start dates, end dates, how many days until the end date from yesterday, how many days have passed since the start date, etc.) and I need these represented in US formats. We have users in Mexico who typically update these documents, and their formatting of DD/MM/YYYY is causing errors in our documentation.

For example, I have the following snippet of code. For reference, the StartDate *should* be **07/01/2023** (July 1st), and the EndDate *should* be **09/30/2023** (Sept 30). While the date formats are represented as US-date mm/dd/yyyy formats when sending the document out, I will get a US-date format for the Start Date, and a MX-date format for the end date when our persons in Mexico complete the macro:

```
...
startdatecol = .Range("3:3").Find(LCase("start date")).Column
enddatecol = .Range("3:3").Find(LCase("end date")).Column

    If Not IsEmpty(.Cells(pacingrow, startdatecol)) Then
        StartDate = Format(.Cells(pacingrow, startdatecol), "[$-409]mm/dd/yyyy") 'US-format for Start Date
    Else
        
        If StartDate = 0 Then
            StartDate = FirstofThisMonth 'Utilizes the first of this month for the Start Date
        Else
            .Cells(pacingrow, startdatecol) = StartDate 'Leaves Blank
        End If
        
    End If
    
    If Not IsEmpty(.Cells(pacingrow, enddatecol)) Then
        EndDate = Format(.Cells(pacingrow, enddatecol), "[$-409]mm/dd/yyyy") ' US format for End Dates
    Else
        
        If EndDate = 0 Then
            EndDate = LastofThisMonth ' End Date Defaults to the Last of This Month
        Else
            .Cells(pacingrow, enddatecol) = EndDate
        End If
        
    End If
 ...
```

Regardless of how this macro is ran, I get a US-formatted Date for StartDate, and an incorrect format for EndDate.

I've also tried running this similar code, which utilizes Function "MakeUSDate" with no success as it will still provide a MX-date format:

```
    If Not IsEmpty(.Cells(pacingrow, enddatecol)) Then
        EndDate = MakeUSDate(.Cells(pacingrow, enddatecol))
    Else
        
        If EndDate = 0 Then
            EndDate = LastofThisMonth
        Else
            .Cells(pacingrow, enddatecol) = EndDate
        End If
 ...

 Function MakeUSDate(DateIn As Variant) As String
 
    ' Do nothing if the value is not a date.
    If Not IsDate(DateIn) Then Exit Function

    ' Format the date value as a U.S. date formatted string expression.
    MakeUSDate = Month(DateIn) & "/" & Day(DateIn) & "/" & Year(DateIn)

End Function
```

Any ideas on how I can implement a solution that will *always* output a US-based date?

Comment: What is the data type for startdatecol and enddatecol ?  I suspect it is string where you  required to obtain the cell date value.  Might also help if use Option Explicit and declare variables when required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Date values carries no format - a format is for display only.

So, pass the clean value:

```
If Not IsEmpty(.Cells(pacingrow, startdatecol)) Then
    StartDate = .Cells(pacingrow, startdatecol)
Else
```